# how to toggle(color change) of two buttons, one clicked then color gets changed and remain changed untill the other is clocked

Tags: javascript, jquery

As I put it in the title, here' what I'm trying to do. two buttons, one clicked then color gets changed and remain changed untill the other is clocked.

currently this is my full code for this

```
<span class="thumb" style="padding-right:7px;"><a href="/post/{{ post.slug }}/vote?is_up=1" class="vote"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i>love</a></span>   
<span class="thumb"><a href="/post/{{ post.slug }}/vote?is_up=0"  class="vote"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-down"></i>hate</a></span>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.thumb').click(function(){
        $('.thumb').css('color', '#333');
        $(this).css('color', '#16A085');
    });

});
</script>
```

simplified version is here;https://jsfiddle.net/zoaxt774/

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, can someone direct me how I should do this

Answer (score 0):

You should change color inside anchor `<a>`:

```
$('.thumb').click(function(){
    $('.thumb a').css('color', '#333');
    $(this).find('a').css('color', '#16A085');
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zoaxt774/1/

Btw there is not included jquery in your fiddle.

If your scenario allows, better add click event to anchor:

```
$('.thumb a').click(function(){
    $('.thumb a').css('color', '#333');
    $(this).css('color', '#16A085');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick: https://jsfiddle.net/2wLvveqo/

IT changes the color when you click one of the links... and the color is locked until you hit the other link. like a toggle. I think that is how you wanted it implemented.

```
$(".thumb a").click(function(e){
    var target =$(e.target); e.preventDefault();
    if(target.data("change")){
        target.css({ color:"red"});
    }else{
        var thumb = $(".thumb [data-change]");
        thumb.css({color:"blue"})
    }
    return false;
})
```

Comment: I dont understand the downvote on this answer.  It seams to do what the OP wants.   I am upvoting to get back to 0

Comment: Aww man... thanks. I think if the question was asked a bit more clearly, there wouldnt be the varying different implementations.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

1. I just simply moved class 'thumb' to the a tag, but you can define your own class

   ```
      <span style="padding-right:7px;"><a href="#" class="thumb">likes</a></span>   
      <span ><a href="#" class="thumb">dislikes</a></span>
   ```
2. $(document).ready(function(){

   ```
       $('a.thumb').click(function(){
           $('a.thumb').not(this).css('color', '#333');
           $(this).css('color', '#16A085');
        });
       });
   ```